# I want to find string in a list that start with ‘A’ in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, slice

I tried

```
List1=[]
for i in name:
If i.startwith(‘A’)
List1.append(i)
Print(List1)
```

How can i find strings that start with ‘A’ in a list and print it but using slicing and not startwith()

Comment: Please fix the code in your question.  It is not valid Python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Do you know how slicing works? Do you know how to compare two strings? You can [edit] to clarify. Please read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In Python `indentation` is very important - try to read the doc. and fix your code.  Also, it's super helpful to provide some sample inputs/outputs to make the question easier to understand.

Comment: Actually the indentation problems come from the edit. The original post was one line, which has syntax problems but not indentation problems

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki In the source it was already multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

**Using slicing:**

```
name = ['Adil','Robert'] #list with names
List1=[]
for i in name:
    if i[:1] == 'A':
        List1.append(i)
print(List1)
```

**Output:**

```
['Adil']
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension with a condition based on a slice might work for you. For example:

```
names = ['Arthur', 'Brian', 'Anthony', '', 'Banana', 'Antirrhinum']

new_list = [name for name in names if name[:1] == 'A']

print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['Arthur', 'Anthony', 'Antirrhinum']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
name = ["Belgium", "Antwerp", "France"]

List1=[]
for i in name:
    if i[0] == "A":
        List1.append(i)
print(List1)
```

Comment: OP wants to use slicing, not indexing. (I didn't downvote though.)

Comment: If the presence of a ":" within the square brackets is this much of importance, you can replace [0] with [:1].

Comment: Slicing is more robust. If a string in the list is empty (i.e., '') then trying to access index 0 will result in IndexError whereas [:1] will return an empty string